# hiding sections with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function showX()

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none"; 

function showZ()

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none"; 

function showY()

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";
```

```css
div {display:inline;}
div img {width:400px;height: 400px;}

#one {
display: none;
}

#two {
display: none;
}

#three {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<section id="one">
take this info es cool 1 
</section>

<section id="two">
take this info es cool 2 
</section>

<section id="three">
take this info es cool 3
</section>

</html>
```

When I click my images nothing happens?
Can anyone give me a hand, please?

I have been trying to work this out for a while so decided to come here.
Thanks in advance for any help!

I am pretty new to programming and I need this for a website project that I am creating.

I need it so when I access the website it will only show the pictures and not the sections. When a picture is clicked it will show the first section but keep the other sections hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing curly brackets `{}`. This is working. You should also call the function.

```js
function showX(){

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none"; 

}

function showZ(){

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "block"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "none"; 

}

function showY(){

document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("two").style.display = "none"; 
document.getElementById("three").style.display = "block";

}

showZ();
```

```css
div {display:inline;}
div img {width:400px;height: 400px;}

#one {
display: none;
}

#two {
display: none;
}

#three {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<section id="one">
take this info es cool 1 
</section>

<section id="two">
take this info es cool 2 
</section>

<section id="three">
take this info es cool 3
</section>

</html>
```